# Rotate Android display without changing orientation

Tags: android, adb, screen-orientation

Essentially what I am trying to complete is having a rectangle monitor sideways (vertical orientation) with the Android display in the Portrait position. Due to limitation of the monitor though it is not viable to rotate the display on the monitor itself. First I set disable the auto rotation and then set it to portrait mode.

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0  
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

I then try to change the resolution to 1920x1080 using the following command

```
adb shell wm size 1920x1080
```

This then throws display back into landscape mode. I would prefer to complete this through adb or any method that would not require additional software.

EDIT:

To clarify I want to emulate the CTRL+ALT+RIGHT ARROW on Windows computer but on an android device preferably through ADB, or any other method besides 3rd party applications.

Comment: have you tried `adb shell wm size 1080x1920`

Comment: Yes, that is the resolution if the display in portrait mode so it has no effect.

Comment: what's the native/original screen resolution?

Comment: It is a dev board running to a monitor that is 1920x1080.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find a relevant answer after some more digging.

Some of this may not be needed but this is what I did to acheive the desired effect. There was also a glitch where Android would not update the rotation so after restarting you have to change the rotation to something else and then back to the original.

```
adb shell root
adb shell remount
adb shell setprop persist.demo.hdmirotation portrait
adb shell setprop persist.demo.hdmirotationlock false
adb shell setprop persist.demo.singledisplay true
adb reboot
adb shell wm size 1080x1920
adb shell wm size 1920x1920
```

The answer was found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117003/allow-rotate-into-portrait-mode-but-do-not-rotate-external-display), and the relevant documentation was found [here](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-97740).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `wm size` unless you want to crop/scale/etc. Just do `settings put system user_rotation 1` or `settings put system user_rotation 3`

Comment: This rotates the display but all objects then rotate after. I want to rotate the display and the screen, if that makes sense at all.